# Assistance in retail tax lab when calling methods (java)

Tags: java, methods

Here is my **output** for this lab. I was wondering if I could get some help. I am a beginner at Java and I need some clarification on calling methods correctly. Any pointers would help.

```
Welcome to the tax collector program!
Enter the total sales for the month
600
The county tax is: 0.0
The state tax is: 0.0
The total tax is 0.0
The county tax is 0.0
The state tax is 0.0
The total tax is 0.0
```

Here is my code below. I'm kinda confused on how to go about fixing it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class retailTax {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double monthlySales = 0;
    double countyTax = 0;
    double stateTax = 0;
    double totalTax = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the tax collector program!");

    inputData(monthlySales);
    calcCounty(monthlySales, countyTax);
    calcState(monthlySales, stateTax);
    calcTotal(stateTax, countyTax, totalTax);
    printData(countyTax, stateTax, totalTax);

}
public static void inputData(double monthlySales)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the total sales for the month");
    monthlySales = input.nextDouble();
}
public static void calcCounty(double monthlySales, double countyTax)
{
    countyTax = monthlySales * .04;

}
public static void calcState(double monthlySales, double stateTax){
    stateTax = monthlySales * .02;

}
public static void calcTotal(double countyTax, double stateTax, double totalTax)
{
    totalTax = countyTax + stateTax;    

}

public static void printData(double countyTax, double stateTax, double totalTax)
{
    System.out.println("The county tax is " + countyTax);
    System.out.println("The state tax is " + stateTax);
    System.out.println("The total tax is " + totalTax);
}
```

}

Comment: The variables in main are only accessible in main. Make them class level and change your parameter names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
calcCounty(monthlySales, countyTax);
```

it is using the methods you just created so this method is called with calcCounty(0, 0). That's because inside `inputData()` your line `monthlySales = input.nextDouble();` is setting the input to the parameter you passed in, not the variable in main. The variables you declared in main are only accessible there. You need to make them class variables

```
public class retailTax {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double monthlySales = 0;
    double countyTax = 0;
    double stateTax = 0;
    double totalTax = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Welcome to the tax collector program!");
        //and so on
```

Next, you should not make the parameters of your methods have the same names as these variables. Not only can it become confusing, but it leads to problems in a lot of cases. Another option would be to make your methods return the values instead of assigning them within. For example, I would change

```
public static void inputData(double monthlySales)
```

to

```
public static double inputData() {
    //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //You don't need this, you already made it
    System.out.println("Enter the total sales for the month");
    return input.nextDouble();
}
```

and use it like

```
monthlySales = inputData();
```

**Side Note**

It is customary to name your classes starting with uppercase letters `RetailTax`.

Comment: I understand completely not. Thank you for taking your time to answer this. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. You should take the time to cast votes on these answers and then accept (click the green check on the left) of whichever one answers your question best.

Comment: I would upvote, but unfortunately I am unable to since I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As @Takendarkk mentioned variables declared inside `main` method are local variables. Following is the updated program with proper way to call methods. Also, its a good java coding practice to have the class name to begin with capital letter.

Following is the updated program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RetailTax {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RetailTax rt = new RetailTax();
        double monthlySales = 0;
        double countyTax = 0;
        double stateTax = 0;
        double totalTax = 0;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the tax collector program!");

        monthlySales = rt.inputData();
        countyTax = rt.calcCounty(monthlySales);
        stateTax = rt.calcState(monthlySales);
        totalTax = rt.calcTotal(countyTax, stateTax);
        rt.printData(countyTax, stateTax, totalTax);

    }
    public double inputData()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the total sales for the month");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double monthlySales = input.nextDouble();
        return monthlySales;
    }
    public double calcCounty(double monthlySales)
    {
        Double countyTax = monthlySales * .04;
        return countyTax;

    }
    public double calcState(double monthlySales){
        Double stateTax = monthlySales * .02;
        return stateTax;

    }
    public double calcTotal(double countyTax, double stateTax)
    {
        Double totalTax = countyTax + stateTax;    
        return totalTax;

    }

    public void printData(double countyTax, double stateTax, double totalTax)
    {
        System.out.println("The county tax is " + countyTax);
        System.out.println("The state tax is " + stateTax);
        System.out.println("The total tax is " + totalTax);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand where I went wrong now. Thank you for taking time to answer my question!

Comment: I would upvote, but not enough rep yet. :(